# Can someone explain the difference between Get-ComputerInfo -Property OSName vs (Get-ComputerInfo).OSName

Tags: powershell

I had some old code for documenting the particulars of my machines when I came across Get-ComputerInfo. So I tried to use it (unsuccessfully) and was almost ready to give up when I came across a way to get what I wanted. But now I'm wondering if anyone can help me understand WHY it works the way it does.

It's pretty simple to illustrate:

```
$OSName1 = Get-ComputerInfo -Property OSName

$OSName2 = (Get-ComputerInfo).OSName

Write-Host $OSName1

Write-Host $OSName2
```

The above yields:

```
@{OsName=Microsoft Windows 11 Pro}

Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
```

I was expecting the 2nd result from the 1st variable. So what's happening differently in those 2 variables? I was expecting them to be the same.

Thanks in advance!

Mark

Comment: The first command returns the object with the property `OsName` and the second command returns the string representation of the property `OsName` of the object.

Comment: `Get-ComputerInfo -Property OSName` returns an object which's __Property__ is `OsName` and has a __Value__. `(Get-ComputerInfo).OSName` __expands the Value__ of the `OSName` Property.

Answer (score 4):

While the comments do explain what you're already seeing, which is that `Get-ComputerInfo -Property OSName` returns an object with that property, what isn't obvious is why the command would do that, instead of returning what you expected: the same thing as `(Get-ComputerInfo).OSName`.

The reason becomes more clear when looking at the help:

```
Get-Help Get-ComputerInfo
```

```
NAME
    Get-ComputerInfo

SYNTAX
    Get-ComputerInfo [[-Property] <string[]>]  [<CommonParameters>]


ALIASES
    gin
```

In the syntax, we can see that `-Property` takes a String *array* and not just a single string.

So you can pass an array of property names to return, like this for example:

```
$info = Get-ComputerInfo -Property OSName, TimeZone, OSProductType

Write-Host $info
```

And then get:

```
@{TimeZone=(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada); OsName=Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise; OsProductType=WorkStation}
```

Now, I did it that way to match your question, but if you just output the value  naturally, or via `Write-Output`, it would look a lot nicer:

```
$info
Write-Output $info
```

```
TimeZone                               OsName                          OsProductType
--------                               ------                          -------------
(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada) Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise   WorkStation
```

Or you could format it:

```
$info | Format-List
```

```
TimeZone      : (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
OsName        : Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
OsProductType : WorkStation
```

**So the answer *why* it returns an object with a single property, it's for consistency for when you request multiple properties (or request none and get them all).**

---

This property selection works exactly the same as if you had used `Select-Object`:

```
$info = Get-ComputerInfo | Select-Object -Property TimeZone, OSName, OSProductType
```

It's also worth noting that `Get-ComputerInfo` is quite slow, and that selecting individual properties does not speed it up in any way, so there is no particular advantage to using the built-in selection vs. selecting after the fact, other than conciseness and readability.

If you need multiple properties, it's *definitely* not a good idea to make multiple calls to `Get-ComputerInfo` with different properties selected, as you're retrieving all the same info on every call and then discarding most of it that way.

If you're unsure which properties you need in the first call, just get them all, and choose them later:

```
$info = Get-ComputerInfo 

if ($condition1) {
    # do thing with $info.OSName
}

if ($condition2) {
    # do thing with $info.TimeZone
}

# etc.
```

Comment: The answer has quite some valuable information on the first syntax, but lacks the information on the second syntax where it actually concerns [access-member enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration) which doesn't show in the particular example of the `Get-ComputerInfo` cmdlet as it would always return a single object which is often not the case for other cmdlets...

Comment: @iRon as you said, this cmdlet always returns a single object, so I'm not sure how access-member enumeration is relevant. I also felt that the second syntax was already straightforward, but I'd welcome an edit if you think that information could be useful, or perhaps even another answer!